# Create anonymous album imgur api version 3

Tags: api, imgur

How do I create an anonymous album (not tied to an account) with the imgur API version 3?

I've tried everything I can think of but I always get either a 403 forbidden or 405 method not allowed...

```
POST https://api.imgur.com/3/album HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Client-ID ***
Host: api.imgur.com
Content-Length: 22
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

{"title":"album title"}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](http://api.imgur.com/models/gallery_album), you set the `account_url` key to `null`.

Comment: Additionally: _"For public read-only and anonymous resources, such as getting image info, looking up user comments, creating an anonymous album, etc. all you need to do is send an authorization header with your client_id along with your requests. This also works if you'd like to upload images anonymously (without the image being tied to an account)."_ http://api.imgur.com/#register

Comment: This looks like information for a GET request, their documentation doesn't mention that parameter for POSTS (http://api.imgur.com/endpoints/album).